# Make a new column based on conditions, data.table R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a function that contains a data.table with specific values:

```
 add_q <- function () {

DT = data.table (X = c("A", "A1", "B", "B1"), Y = c("C", "C1", "D", "D1"))}
```

This will give my two columns X and Y with the values. I want to make a 3rd column that would have the values YES for values that have A, C, A1, C1 and the value NO for the rest.

How to do that?

Comment: You want it inside the function? Also, what did you try?

Answer (score 1):

Updated shortened code (many thanks to @B. Christian Kamgang:

Using `fifelse` we could do something like this:

```
library(data.table)

add_q <- function (DT, Z) {

  setDT(DT)[, Z :=  fifelse(grepl("A|C", X) | grepl("A|C", Y), "Yes", "NO")]
  DT
  }

DT = data.table (X = c("A", "A1", "B", "B1"), Y = c("C", "C1", "D", "D1"))

add_q(DT, Z)
DT

    X  Y   Z
1:  A  C YES
2: A1 C1 YES
3:  B  D  NO
4: B1 D1  NO
```

Comment: Note that you can avoid to call `fifelse` twice using `fifelse(grepl("A|C", X) | grepl("A|C", Y), "Yes", "NO")`.

Answer (score 1):

We can try `grepl` like below

```
DT[
  ,
  Z := fifelse(
    Reduce(`&`, lapply(.SD, grepl, pattern = "^(A|C)")), 
    "YES", 
    "NO"
  )
]
```

which gives

```
> DT
    X  Y   Z
1:  A  C YES
2: A1 C1 YES
3:  B  D  NO
4: B1 D1  NO
```